# Problem uploading app to google app engine

Tags: http, google-app-engine, proxy

I'm having problems uploading an app to the google-app-engine from my work place. I believe the problem is related to proxy, because I do not see the same problem when following the same procedure from home. (I do not specify HTTP_PROXY from home).

These are the commands I run (hostname replaced):

```
set HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy.myhostname.com:8080
set HTTPS_PROXY=http://proxy.myhostname.com:8080
appcfg.py --insecure update myappfolder
```

When running the commands I get prompted for email and password, as expected, but after that it immediately exits with this errormessage:

```
Error 302: --- begin server output ---
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Moved Temporarily</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Moved Temporarily</H1>
The document has moved <A HREF="https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin">here</A>.
</BODY>
</HTML>
--- end server output ---
```

Note: I added the --insecure option because else it gave a warning of missing ssl module.

Any idea how to solve or workaround this problem?

Comment: Tried `export HTTP_PROXY='...'`?

Comment: Should
'set HTTP_PROXY=https://proxy.myhostname.com:8080'
actually be
'set HTTPS_PROXY=https://proxy.myhostname.com:8080'
Maybe then you won't receive a missing ssl module warning.

Comment: Edit: forgot to add "set" in front of proxy variable, but only in this text though. The export keyword does not work on windows, which is the platform I'm using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same problem.
Running with --noisy "appcfg.py --noisy update e:\myappip --insecure" I get some more verbose logs

```
2012-10-17 06:42:47,641 DEBUG appengine_rpc.py:401 Got http error, this is try #1
2012-10-17 06:42:47,641 DEBUG appengine_rpc.py:420 Got 302 redirect. Location:https://appengine.google.com/api/updatecheck?release=1.7.2&timestamp=1345557405&runtime=python27&api_versions=%5B'1'%5D 
2012-10-17 06:42:47,772 INFO appcfg.py:608 Update check failed: HTTP Error 302: Found
2012-10-17 06:42:47,832 INFO appcfg.py:2157 Reading app configuration.
2012-10-17 06:42:48,062 DEBUG appengine_rpc.py:389 Sending HTTP request:
POST /api/appversion/getresourcelimits?version=23&app_id=pergasoft HTTP/1.1
Host: appengine.google.com
X-appcfg-api-version: 1
Content-type: application/octet-stream
User-agent: appcfg_py/1.7.2 win32/5.1.2600.2 Python/2.7.2.final.0

2012-10-17 07:11:10,430 ERROR appcfg.py:2199 An error occurred processing file '': HTTP Error 302: Found. Aborting.
Error 302: --- begin server output ---

--- end server output ---
```

In my case **finally help**  **remove --insecure directive** Before that step I spend many hours by googling some solution.

Some steps I do before (probably unnecessary):

- Repair TCP/IP sockets with commnad  "netsh int ip reset resetlog.txt"
- Upgrade google appengine from GoogleAppEngine-1.7.0 to
- GoogleAppEngine-1.7.2 Upgrade/reinstall Python version from 2.7.2 to
  2.7.3

Probably the problem was with connection to RPC server and the reason may be the redirection to httpS with --insecure directive together.

This problem happend without any code change on my side, so probably it is problem on Google side.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the relevant section from the Google [docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp.html#Using_an_HTTP_Proxy).

**Using an HTTP Proxy**

If you are running appcfg.py behind an HTTP proxy, you must tell appcfg.py the name of the proxy. To set an HTTP proxy for appcfg.py, set the http_proxy and https_proxy environment variables.

*Using Windows (in Command Prompt):*

```
set HTTP_PROXY=http://cache.mycompany.com:3128
set HTTPS_PROXY=http://cache.mycompany.com:3128
appcfg.py update myapp
```

*Using the command line in Mac OS X (in Terminal) or Linux:*

```
export http_proxy="http://cache.mycompany.com:3128"
appcfg.py update myapp
```

By default, appcfg.py uses HTTPS to communicate with App Engine. If you require that it use HTTP instead, you can turn off HTTPS with the --insecure option:

```
appcfg.py --insecure update myapp
```

Comment: The procedure you're referring to is the exact procedure I was following. Tried both with and without --insecure.

Comment: No, the commands you have posted show that you're setting HTTP_PROXY twice. You should be setting HTTP_PROXY and also HTTPS_PROXY (they are different and this one has an S after HTTP). I have already posted this as comment to your original post.

Comment: @mrl33t You are certainly right about the misplaced S, thank you for pointing that out. Unfortunately the fix doesn't solve my initial problem, so I still get the 302 error message.